# angularJS1.4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

My html code：

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mail.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var myapp=angular.module('mail', ['ngRoute']);
```

But I get

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Why?

Comment: angular and angular-route same version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please load jquery library first then load angularjs library, then ngRouter library see following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mail.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load JS files in order jQuery>Bootstrap>angular>route>mail. Also verify the version number of angular, ng-route you are using in your application. If not sure, use cdn.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.17/angular.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.17/angular-route.min.js